# SOAP and REST Services in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, soap

I am learning parsing in iPhone, When i was searching for the tutorials, i came to know very  little bit about SOAP and REST services.

Now i wanted to learn SOAP and REST services.

Do any one have theoretical knowledge of SOAP and REST?
Is there any simple tutorial available for the beginners?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see these links, alongwith comparison of both

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest

http://greatgandhi.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/soap-vs-rest-%E2%80%93-the-best-webservice/

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm

Answer (score 2):

SOAP GUIDE

```
http://sudzc.com/
```

REST GUIDE

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630306/iphone-rest-client
```

Answer (score 1):

SOAP Web Service

```
 -(IBAction) read_data
 {
  NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">n"
                         "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>n"
                         "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n",name.text
                         ];



NSLog(@"soap Message= %@",soapMessage);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL "]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[webData setLength: 0];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
[webData appendData:data];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
[connection release];
[webData release];
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"theXML %@",theXML);    // Here is your received Value from url
[theXML release];
 }
```

Here is the Example of [RESTful WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452154/iphone-restful-webservices)